# undefined reference to operator<<

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

I have a regular class (not a template, that is) with a private friend operator<<

it's declaration is:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Position& position);
```

in the cpp file it's definition is:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Position& position)
{
  out << position.getXPoint() << "," << position.getYPoint();
  return out;
}
```

it is being compiled then linked to the main function which uses it, however when I use it I get an undefined reference...

however when I add the definition to the top of the main cpp file and remove the friend declaration, it works fine...

heres how I am using it in my main function

```
std::cout << node->getPosition() << std::endl;
```

no more no less...

heres the linker error

> /home/luke/Desktop/pathfinder/parse_world.cpp:34: undefined reference to `pathfinder::operator<<(std::ostream&, pathfinder::Position const&)'

and heres the class header...

```
#ifndef PATHFINDER_H
#define PATHFINDER_H
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstring>
namespace pathfinder
{
class Node;
typedef unsigned int GCost;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<Node*> > World;
typedef std::vector<Node*> WorldRow;
class Position
{
public:
    typedef unsigned int point_type;
private:
    point_type* xPoint_;
    point_type* yPoint_;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Position& position);
public:
    Position(const point_type& xPoint = 0, const point_type& yPoint = 0);
    Position(const Position& position);
    Position(Position&& position);
    ~Position();

    Position& operator=(const Position& position);
    Position& operator=(Position&& position);

    point_type getXPoint() const;
    point_type getYPoint() const;

    void setXPoint(const point_type& xPoint);
    void setYPoint(const point_type& yPoint);
};
class Node
{
private:
    bool* isPassable_;
    bool* isStartingNode_;
    bool* isTargetNode_;
    Position* position_;
    GCost* additionalGCost_;
    Node* parent_;
public:
    Node(const bool& isPassable = true, const bool& isStartingNode = false, const bool& isTargetNode = false, const Position& position = Position(0,0), const GCost& additionalGCost = 0, Node* parent = nullptr);
    Node(const Node& node);
    Node(Node&& node);
    ~Node();

    Node& operator=(const Node& node);
    Node& operator=(Node&& node);

    bool isPassable() const;
    bool isStartingNode() const;
    bool isTargetNode() const;
    Position getPosition() const;
    GCost getAdditionalGCost() const;
    Node* getParent() const;

    void setAsPassable(const bool& isPassable);
    void setAsStartingNode(const bool& isStartingNode);
    void setAsTargetNode(const bool& isTargetNode);
    void setPosition(const Position& position);
    void setAdditionalGCost(const GCost& additionalGCost);
    void setParent(Node* parent);
};
class WorldHelper
{
public:
    static World fromStream(std::istream& input);
    static void syncPositions(World& world);
    static void uninitializeWorld(World& world);
    static Node* findStartingNode(const World& world);
    static Node* findTargetNode(const World& world);
};
class Pathfinder
{
public:
    virtual std::list<Node*> operator()(World& world) const = 0;
};
};
#endif //PATHFINDER_H
```

now after removing the friend declaration I am getting error messages like:

> cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream&&’

it is occuring on the same line as the std::cout statement...

So, whats the deal...

thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like your cpp file isn't linking properly. Does anything else in there work?

Comment: Can you post how you are calling it in the main function?

Comment: Yes, everything else works, like constructors, and destructors

Comment: I agree with chris. This is a classic linkage problem based on what you said about it working when moved into the same file.  Check your Solution to make sure everything is included correctly.

Comment: Also, note that access specifiers are meaningless for friend functions.

Comment: @K-ballo You're right! I've been declaring friend operators `public` for no good reason! Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual text of the error?

Comment: The obvious question now is are you enclosing the definition within  `namespace pathfinder`?

Comment: yes I am, should I be declaring it in a global namespace, wait, stupid question... of course

Comment: but how do I incorporate this global function with my header

Comment: No, in fact your operator should be declared within `namespace pathfinder`. ADL will kick in and call your specific operator, you don't need -and in fact shouldn't- place it in the global namespace.

Comment: Can you post the header file of your class?  That would help us to see if something is wrong syntactically that's causing the compiler to generate a symbol other than what you expect.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `namespace pathfinder` in your header at all. Are you doing something funky with namespaces, perhaps like `namespace pathfinder { #include "..." }`?

Comment: oh, no not at all, I just dropped some other class definitions, I'll add the header part now...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My guess, from the description is that you are declaring two `operator<<` but only defining one. For example:

```
namespace A {
   struct B {
      friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, B const & ); // [1]
   };
}
std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, A::B const & ) {        // [2]
   return o;
}
```

The line [1] declares one `A::operator<<` function that can be found through ADL on the type `B`, but [2] declares and defines `::operator<<`. When the compiler sees the code:

```
A::B b;
std::cout << b;
```

It use ADL and find `A::operator<<` (from the friend declaration) and use it, but that function is undefined. If you remove the `friend` declaration, there is a single instance of `operator<<` declared and defined in the global namespace and that will be found by regular lookup.

Also note that this can be harder to spot if there are using directives in your program, as the definition in [2] might not explicitly name the `A` namespace for the argument. This would also explain that you can *define* the rest of the members of the type:

```
// cpp [assume that the definition of B contained a member f
using namespace A;
void B::f() {
}
```

The definition of `B::f` resides (in code) in the global namespace, but because of the using directive, `B` will be found in the `A` namespace and the type specifier will be equivalent to `A::B` what makes the definition equivalent to `void ::A::B::f() {}` after resolving `B`. This will **not** happen for free functions.

I would recommend that you avoid using directives as they allow for subtle errors like this one. Also note that you can actually *define* the operator in the namespace explicitly (but you will need to also *declare* it in the namespace:

```
namespace A {
   struct B  { friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, B const & ); };
   std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, B const & );
}
std::ostream& A::operator<<( std::ostream& o, B const & ) {
   return o;
}
```

This trick (defining free functions outside of their natural namespace by fully qualifying) is sometimes use to avoid the definition of the function implicitly declaring it, which is prone to this type of errors. For example, if you defined the operator in the proper namespace, but the signature was slightly different:

```
namespace A {
   struct B  {
      friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, B const & ); // [1]
   };
   std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&, B & ) {                // [3]
      return o;
   }
}
```

The definition in [3] is also a declaration, but it declares a function different than the one declared in [1], and you might end up scratching your head asking why the linker is not finding [1].

Comment: I got rid of the friend declaration and now I am getting errors like error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’

Comment: @LukeSanAntonio, could you post those and which lines they occur on?

Comment: @LukeSanAntonio: That means that the compiler is not finding the appropriate overload to `operator<<` and it is defaulting to a generic version in C++11: `template <typename T> std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream&&, const T& );`

Comment: @LukeSanAntonio: Even after the *hint* in this answer, you have failed to provide the definition (with all enclosing namespaces) in the cpp file. You are also not providing the namespaces in the definition of the type...

Comment: @LukeSanAntonio: Is there any way to be explicit? What do you mean? You have a problem: you are declaring a function as a friend and defining a different function. That is unrelated to being explicit, but rather an error on your side. You should *define* the function in the same namespace that you are declaring it a friend, or otherwise, you should befriend the appropriate function (qualify the friend declaration). That is, you need to make both the friend declaration and the actual overload refer to the same function (I would recommend in `A` namespace)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, I was wondering where exactly that rvalue reference on the ostream was coming from... I didn't know C++11 had a generic version.

Comment: why is the function friended in the class a different one than the one declared, aren't they the same... (in the pathfinder namespace)

Comment: I mean, doesn't a friend'd function route to the containing namespace

Comment: @LukeSanAntonio: Is your defined `operator<<` in the `pathfinder` namespace? You are not showing the code where/how the function is defined. Consider the snippet in the answer: the friend declaration declares `::A::operator<<`, but the definition (outside of `A`) declares and defines `::operator<<`. That would be the problem. The `friend` declaration does (kind of) declare a function in the enclosing namespace (i.e. `pathfinder`), and that is the one picked by the compiler, but you don't have a definition for it, and thus the linker complains.

Comment: ... I think that the answer does deal with this, and with why it might seem to work for member functions defined at the same level that the `operator<<`... Is there any part of the answer for which you want some clarification?

Comment: What I am wondering is, why are you assuming that the definition of the function is not in the namespace, it is. I have a using directive in my cpp file, therefore any function not belonging to a class will be return_type pathfinder::function_name(params), so where did you get the idea that the operator declared in the class as a friend is different from the actual definition

Comment: @LukeSanAntonio: You have not understood the part about the `using` directive. It does not mean that everything in the cpp will be in that namespace, only that lookup will find types in that namespace. If you want *everything* to be in the namespace, just open it `namespace pathfinder {` add the code there and close it `}`. Alternatively, you can qualify the definition: `std::ostream& pathfinder::operator<< ...`. Please reread the answer (the part relating to the `using` directive...

Comment: I think I understand, your saying that when I put a `using namespace pathfinder` the reason I don't need to add the `pathfinder::` is because the statement adds it implicitly, however I still don't understand why this is creating a weird declaration that is screwing up the ADL

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11613/discussion-between-david-rodriguez-dribeas-and-luke-san-antonio)

Comment: just changed the using namespace pathfinder; to a namespace block and it worked just as expected, thanks for putting up for my misunderstanding

Answer (score 2):

David gave a very good answer to the question.  Here I am just providing an example for easy understanding.

in my header file:

```
namespace BamTools {
class SomeBamClass {
.....
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ous, const SomeBamClass& ba);
    .....
}
}
```

In the cpp file:

```
using namespace BamTools; // this work for Class member function but not friends
using namespace std;

........
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &ous, const SomeBamClass &ba) {
  // actual implementation
  return ous;
}
```

The above will give you undefined reference to operator<<(.., const SomeBamClass&) when you try to link to this library from your own applications because it is declaration and implementation of an operator outside the namespace.

```
undefined reference to `BamTools::operator<<(std::ostream&, BamTools::SomeBamClass const&)'
```

The only thing works for me is to add namespace inclosure to the friend function in the implementation file:

```
namespace BamTools {
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &ous, const SomeBamClass &ba) {
...
   return ous;
}
}
```

using ... BamTools::operator<<(..., const BamTools::SomeBamClass&) will result in a compiler error for my g++ 5.4.0.