# what does undefined reference to operator<<.... means? in c++

Tags: c++, class, function, friend

I have friend function in the class. (in header file. head.h) i have implemented in head.cpp
and in head.h outside of the class i have ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, TreeNode* ptr);
i implemented in head.cpp as well. Is there any problem with that?

Header file

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const TreeDB& ptr);
 ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, TreeNode* ptr);
```

Implementation

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, TreeNode* ptr)
{
 if(rhs!=NULL)
 {
  operator<<(out,ptr->Left());
  out<<(*(ptr->Entry()));
  operator<<(out,ptr->Right());
 }
 return out;
}




ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const TreeDB& ptr)
{
 return (operator<<(out,ptr.root));
}
```

Error: undefined reference to 'operator<<(std::basic_ostream >&,DBentry const&)'

DBentry is another class which manipulates the database entry

Comment: Why don't you show us your actual code instead of describing it?

Comment: You get "undefined reference to..." error messages from the linker, and it can indicate that you miss a file when linking your project.

Comment: because i don't think this error occurs because of logic error, its something about declaration part

Comment: It is still easier to quickly assess how the declarations and definitions relate if you see them written out, rather than have them described in lengthy natural language.

Comment: when i compile my files seperately, no error occurs, but when i combine them it writes undefined reference

Comment: "Is there any problem with that?" ... Is there any problem with *what*? .. "its something about declaration part" - then show us the declarations and their points of usage. If you want help, oblige the ones that can help you. While you're at it the **exact** error message please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined reference to operator<<](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712380/undefined-reference-to-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you got an undefined reference it is often an symptom of either a missing function definition, a small difference in signature from the definition and the declaration or that the definition of the function is not compiled/linked in.

So check that your arguments match, that the namespaces match, and that the definition of the function indeed is compiled.

As far as I can see in the code you have provided you have not defined an operator<< for `DBEntry& const`.

Comment: friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const TreeDB& rhs);ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, TreeNode* rhs); these are in my header file

Comment: and these are my implementation part ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, TreeNode* rhs)
{
 if(rhs!=NULL)
 {
  operator<<(out,rhs->getLeft());
  out<<(*(rhs->getEntry()));
  operator<<(out,rhs->getRight());
 }
 return out;
}




ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const TreeDB& rhs)
{
 return (operator<<(out,rhs.root));
}

Comment: @user1722022 update your code to your question instead of as comment in here

Comment: check namespaces also, but first of all check the compiler/linker output that the cpp file in question is compiled and linked in.

Comment: now it compiled but output from my program is 0x9bc61380x9bc61000x9bc6158>

Comment: @user1722022 sounds like three pointers stuffed together. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: no, i dont want to print pointers, i want to print the data which stored at that pointers.

Comment: @user1722022 then you probably want to use the * operator on the pointers, after you check them for nullptr.

Comment: @user1722022 glad to be of help. Next time give more details when you ask, then you'll probably get less flac :)

Answer (score 2):

Your global function for TreeDB printing is friended in your class definition (we're assuming) as:

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const TreeDB& ptr);
```

You later define it as

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const TreeDB& ptr)
{
   return (operator<<(out,ptr.root));
}
```

Notice: **`ptr` is const; therefore `ptr.root` is const as well**

Now look at your node pointer operator:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, TreeNode* ptr)
```

`ptr` is not const, and therefore this operator does not apply. it should be:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const TreeNode* ptr)
```

Once you fix that. your error message:

> Error: undefined reference to 'operator<<(std::basic_ostream >&,DBentry const&)'

This is almost guaranteed to be because you don't have the following:

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const DBEntry& entry);
```

It is highly likely if you do have an operator like this it was not declared with a `const` qualifier on the right-hand-side in the same way you didn't declare `const TreeNode*` correctly in its `operator <<()`.

Comment: i added const but it shows same error again.

Comment: now it compiled but output from my program is
0x9bc61380x9bc61000x9bc6158>

Comment: Those would be pointer values. At least you're making progress. Personally I would ditch all operators except the const TreeDB& and maybe DBEntry operator, instead implementing `write(ostream&) const;` members for each class that needs to dump to an output stream, but your compilation error is fixed, so thats a good thing.

Comment: this because out<<(*(rhs->getEntry())) when i delete the star it prints pointer not what stored at that pointer. how can i fix it?

Comment: @user1722022 Don't delete the *, and make damn sure Entry() isn't null before calling that operator..